# Как уменьшить длину url товара в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

На сегодняшний день имеем вот такой URL:

```
http://site.com/catalog/sredstva-primenyaemye-pri-zabolevaniyakh-pecheni-i-zhelchevyvodyashchikh-putey/essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/
```

С точки зрения СЕО, явно будет более преимущественным URL вида:

```
http://site.com/essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/
```

Как в Битрикс можно реализовать задуманное?

**/catalog/index.php**:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog", 
".default", 
array(
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "site",
    "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
    "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/cart/",
    "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
    "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
    "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
    "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
    "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
    "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
    "SEF_FOLDER" => "/",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "Y",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
    "ADD_SECTION_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    "USE_ELEMENT_COUNTER" => "N",
    "USE_FILTER" => "Y",
    "FILTER_NAME" => "\$Filter",
    "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "VERTICAL",
    "FILTER_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "FILTER_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "FILTER_PRICE_CODE" => array(
        0 => "BASE",
    ),
    "FILTER_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
        1 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
        2 => "",
    ),
    "FILTER_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "USE_REVIEW" => "Y",
    "MESSAGES_PER_PAGE" => "12",
    "USE_CAPTCHA" => "Y",
    "REVIEW_AJAX_POST" => "Y",
    "PATH_TO_SMILE" => "/bitrix/images/forum/smile/",
    "FORUM_ID" => "2",
    "URL_TEMPLATES_READ" => "",
    "SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM" => "Y",
    "USE_COMPARE" => "N",
    "PRICE_CODE" => array(
        0 => "BASE",
    ),
    "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
    "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
    "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
    "PRICE_VAT_SHOW_VALUE" => "N",
    "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
    ),
    "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
    "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "Y",
    "CURRENCY_ID" => "UAH",
    "QUANTITY_FLOAT" => "N",
    "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(
        0 => "SIZES_SHOES",
        1 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
        2 => "COLOR_REF",
    ),
    "SHOW_TOP_ELEMENTS" => "N",
    "SECTION_COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
    "SECTION_TOP_DEPTH" => "1",
    "SECTIONS_VIEW_MODE" => "TILE",
    "SECTIONS_SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
    "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "15",
    "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "TITLE",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "A",
    "LIST_META_KEYWORDS" => "UF_KEYWORDS",
    "LIST_META_DESCRIPTION" => "UF_META_DESCRIPTION",
    "LIST_BROWSER_TITLE" => "UF_BROWSER_TITLE",
    "LIST_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "NAME",
        1 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
        2 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
        3 => "",
    ),
    "LIST_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "SIZES_SHOES",
        1 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
        2 => "COLOR_REF",
        3 => "MORE_PHOTO",
        4 => "ARTNUMBER",
        5 => "",
    ),
    "LIST_OFFERS_LIMIT" => "0",
    "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "ARTNUMBER",
        1 => "MANUFACTURER",
        2 => "COUNTRY",
        3 => "TYPE",
        4 => "MATERIAL",
        5 => "",
    ),
    "DETAIL_META_KEYWORDS" => "KEYWORDS",
    "DETAIL_META_DESCRIPTION" => "META_DESCRIPTION",
    "DETAIL_BROWSER_TITLE" => "TITLE",
    "DETAIL_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "NAME",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "DETAIL_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "ARTNUMBER",
        1 => "SIZES_SHOES",
        2 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
        3 => "COLOR_REF",
        4 => "MORE_PHOTO",
        5 => "",
    ),
    "LINK_IBLOCK_TYPE" => "",
    "LINK_IBLOCK_ID" => "",
    "LINK_PROPERTY_SID" => "",
    "LINK_ELEMENTS_URL" => "link.php?PARENT_ELEMENT_ID=#ELEMENT_ID#",
    "USE_ALSO_BUY" => "Y",
    "ALSO_BUY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "4",
    "ALSO_BUY_MIN_BUYES" => "1",
    "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => "desc",
    "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "round",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "MORE_PHOTO",
    "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
    "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "Y",
    "OFFER_ADD_PICT_PROP" => "MORE_PHOTO",
    "OFFER_TREE_PROPS" => array(
        0 => "SIZES_SHOES",
        1 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
        2 => "COLOR_REF",
        3 => "",
    ),
    "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "Y",
    "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "Y",
    "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
    "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
    "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнение",
    "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
    "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
    "DETAIL_USE_VOTE_RATING" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_VOTE_DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => "rating",
    "DETAIL_USE_COMMENTS" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_BLOG_USE" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_VK_USE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_FB_USE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "USE_STORE" => "Y",
    "USE_STORE_PHONE" => "Y",
    "USE_STORE_SCHEDULE" => "Y",
    "USE_MIN_AMOUNT" => "N",
    "STORE_PATH" => "/store/#store_id#",
    "MAIN_TITLE" => "Наличие на складах",
    "MIN_AMOUNT" => "10",
    "DETAIL_BRAND_USE" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_BRAND_PROP_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "BRAND_REF",
        2 => "",
    ),
    "SIDEBAR_SECTION_SHOW" => "Y",
    "SIDEBAR_DETAIL_SHOW" => "Y",
    "SIDEBAR_PATH" => "/catalog/sidebar.php",
    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "COMMON_SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY" => "N",
    "DETAIL_BLOG_URL" => "catalog_comments",
    "DETAIL_BLOG_EMAIL_NOTIFY" => "N",
    "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "Y",
    "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "Y",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "USE_SALE_BESTSELLERS" => "N",
    "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "N",
    "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
    "USE_COMMON_SETTINGS_BASKET_POPUP" => "N",
    "COMMON_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
    "TOP_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
    "SECTION_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
    "DETAIL_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => array(
        0 => "ADD",
    ),
    "DETAIL_SHOW_BASIS_PRICE" => "Y",
    "SECTIONS_HIDE_SECTION_NAME" => "N",
    "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_CHECK_SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "N",
    "SHOW_DEACTIVATED" => "N",
    "DETAIL_DETAIL_PICTURE_MODE" => "IMG",
    "DETAIL_ADD_DETAIL_TO_SLIDER" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT_MODE" => "E",
    "STORES" => array(
    ),
    "USER_FIELDS" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "FIELDS" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "SHOW_EMPTY_STORE" => "Y",
    "SHOW_GENERAL_STORE_INFORMATION" => "N",
    "USE_BIG_DATA" => "N",
    "BIG_DATA_RCM_TYPE" => "bestsell",
    "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
    "SHOW_404" => "Y",
    "MESSAGE_404" => "",
    "SECTION_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "USE_GIFTS_DETAIL" => "Y",
    "USE_GIFTS_SECTION" => "Y",
    "USE_GIFTS_MAIN_PR_SECTION_LIST" => "Y",
    "GIFTS_DETAIL_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "GIFTS_DETAIL_HIDE_BLOCK_TITLE" => "N",
    "GIFTS_DETAIL_BLOCK_TITLE" => "Выберите один из подарков",
    "GIFTS_DETAIL_TEXT_LABEL_GIFT" => "Подарок",
    "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_HIDE_BLOCK_TITLE" => "N",
    "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_BLOCK_TITLE" => "Подарки к товарам этого раздела",
    "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_TEXT_LABEL_GIFT" => "Подарок",
    "GIFTS_SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "Y",
    "GIFTS_SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "Y",
    "GIFTS_SHOW_NAME" => "Y",
    "GIFTS_SHOW_IMAGE" => "Y",
    "GIFTS_MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Выбрать",
    "GIFTS_MAIN_PRODUCT_DETAIL_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "GIFTS_MAIN_PRODUCT_DETAIL_HIDE_BLOCK_TITLE" => "N",
    "GIFTS_MAIN_PRODUCT_DETAIL_BLOCK_TITLE" => "Выберите один из товаров, чтобы получить подарок",
    "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
    "DETAIL_SET_VIEWED_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
    "FILE_404" => "",
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
        "sections" => "/catalog/",
        "section" => "#SECTION_CODE#/",
        "element" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        "compare" => "compare/",
        "smart_filter" => "#SECTION_CODE#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",
    )
),
false
```

);

**urlrewrite.php**:

```
...    
array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/#",
        "RULE" => "",
        "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
        "PATH" => "/catalog/index.php",
    ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такое понятие как ЧПУ оно строиться из настроек компонента и инфоблока исходя из заданных параметров.

Как я вижу у вас URL формируется исходя из физического раздела `/catalog/` потом символьный код раздела из базы данных `/sredstva-primenyaemye-pri-zabolevaniyakh-pecheni-i-zhelchevyvodyashchikh-putey/` и потом символьный код самого элемента таким образом компонент `catalog` парсит URL и проверяет есть ли у нас в базе такой элемент, а вы хотите избавиться от `/catalog/` по нем в корня сайта в файле `urlrewrite.php` есть правило обработки, т.е если у нас есть правило в `urlrewrite.php` в котором есть `/catalog/` то он отдает на обработку битрикса если нет то 404, далее компонент уже разбирает URL и проверяет в базе есть ли такой элемент и затем делает переадресацию на нужный файл шаблона.

Теперь как реализовать задуманное:

1. В инфоблоке каталога в настройках меняем детальный URL на #SITE_DIR##ELEMENT_CODE#/
2. В настройках компонента каталога нужно изменить SELF_FOLDER на /
3. В urlrewrite.php нужно найти правило в котором есть /catalog/ и перенести его в самый конец файла и изменить CONDITION на #^/#
4. Затем в шаблоне компонента каталога или в своем компоненте типа котроллера вам нужно проверять самостоятельно есть ли такой элемент в каталоге если нет отдавать 404 ошибку так же учесть что разделы вам теперь нужно самостоятельно тоже отлавливать и проверять, а то у вас по любому URL будет доступен сайт и это плохо для с SEO
5. Если поисковики уже индексировали сайт нужно настроить 301 редиректы со старых URL /catalog/sredstva-primenyaemye-pri-zabolevaniyakh-pecheni-i-zhelchevyvodyashchikh-putey/essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/ на новые /essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/
6. Переиндексировать сайт
7. Проверить что бы все остальные страницы в том числе и ваши корректно работали, возможно возникнет проблема с разделами в каталоге
8. Если символьные коды разделов большие то их нужно изменить что бы была ссылка короче на раздел
   Как видим задача это не простая так как в битриксе используется статически разделы и динамические и роутингом частично занимается apache и компоненты bitrix как бы битрикс не расчитан на такие действия и очень не советую так делать.

Возможно вам помогут более простые действия например сократить символьные коды разделов и URL автоматически станет меньше нужно будет только настроить редиректы 301 со старых URL на новые если поисковые боты уже индексировали эти страницы и сделать переиндексацию.

Так же возможно вам помогут короткие ссылки можно про это почитать [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=3080&LESSON_PATH=3905.4461.3080)

Comment: после выполнения первых трех пунктов товар уже должен быть доступен по ссылке https://site.com/essentsiale-n-kapsuly-30/?

Comment: сейчас возвращается 404

Comment: @Сергей да товар должен быть доступен, приложите код вызова компонента и код urlrewrite.php

Comment: приложил файлы к сообщению

Comment: @Сергей исправьте "element" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/"

Comment: к сожалению, ничего не поменялось

Comment: @Сергей вот смотрите пример http://newbitrix.flex.by/slippers-pink-paradise/
/catalog/index.php https://yadi.sk/i/BWVxWvi4L6YRIw
urlrewrite.php
https://yadi.sk/i/ST7Ago2EkBhULw

Comment: #SECTION_CODE#/ заменил на #SECTION_CODE_PATH#/ и заработало

Comment: кстати, каталог, который был по адресу /catalog перестал отображаться, он ведь теперь настроен от корня. Как -то можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84046/discussion-between---and-).